# Struts passing parameters from jsp to action

Tags: java, struts

I work with Struts 2.2.

I have iterated over an `ArrayList` of users. I have an edit link for each user.

When the edit link is clicked I want to find the user in a database and display its properties.

Unfortunately the link does not take me to the desired page, instead it redirects me to the same page. Any ideas?

display.jsp:

```xml
<logic:iterate id="customerElement" name="ACTIVE_PROFILES_LIST" property="list">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <bean:write name="customerElement" property="lastName"/>
    </td>

    <td>
      <bean:write name="customerElement" property="firstName"/>
    </td>

    <td>
      <pdk-html:link action="/beforeEditProfile.do?toEdit=${customerElement.login}">Edit</pdk-html:link>
    </td>
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Action class:

```
public class BeforeBeforeEditProfileAction(){

  public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                               HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
                                                                    ServletException {


 // retrieve the parameter


    String toModify= request.getParameter("toEdit");  
    SearchBean search = new SearchBean();
    Cetatean cet = search.getSingleCitizen(toModify);
    LogManager.info("BeforeEditProfileAction: ENTER");
    if(cet!=null){
        request.setAttribute("cetatean", cet);
        LogManager.info("BeforeEditProfileAction: cetatean not null");
        return mapping.findForward("succes");
    }
    else {  
        LogManager.info("BeforeEditProfileAction: cetatean null");
        return  mapping.findForward("failure");
    }

  }
 }
```

struts-config.xml

```xml
<action path="/beforeEditProfile" type="pm.action.BeforeEditProfileAction" name="user" validate="true" scope="request" input="/htdocs/pages/display.jsp">
  <forward name="success" path="/htdocs/pages/editProfile.jsp"/>
  <forward name="failure" path="/htdocs/pages/profileEditedFailed.jsp"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean Struts **1**.2? Because this isn't Struts 2 at all. Did you check the rendered HTML to see what the link looks like? Does whatever tag library "pdk-html" is follow the normal S1 tag lib usage, or is it different?

Comment: Have you debugged your Action? What are the ommitted lines of your action, cause that's where everything happens. Is value of **toModify** correct?

Comment: 1.2 sorry.Yes,I have checked it.it adds something to the old link:

Comment: ?_piref97_96042_97_82497_82507.strutsAction=%2FbeforeEditProfile.do%3Bjsessionid%3DGB5qQ1xGfp3cQ4S758HB1p8Q2TQQmPvXzHk1b1ylw7G6vTnvx7sZ!-1222996271%3FtoEdit%3D.